# Find product of two numbers using addition and subtraction only?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

This is my problem statement.
`Given two integers m & n, calculate and return their multiplication using recursion. You can only use subtraction and addition for your calculation. No other operators are allowed.`

This is my approach.

```
def mult(m,n):
    if m == 0 or n == 0:
        return 0
    if n == 1:
        return m
    if m == 1:
        return n
    if m < 0 and n < 0:
        return mult(-m, -n)
    if n < 0:
        return -mult(m, -n)
    if m < 0:
        return -mult(-m, n)
    return m + mult(m, n - 1) 

m = int(input())
n = int(input())
print (mult(m, n))
```

One of the test case is showing Runtime Error.
Could someone please tell me what is problem with my code. I have also taken care of negative values.

```
Runtime Error
Traceback (most recent call last): File Main.py , line 18, in <module> print (mult(m, n)) 
File Main.py , line 14, in mult return m + mult(m, n - 1) 
File Main.py , line 14, in mult return m + mult(m, n - 1) 
File Main.py , line 14, in mult return m + mult(m, n - 1) 
File Main.py , line 14, in mult return m + mult(m, n - 1) 
File Main.py , line 14, in mult return m + mult(m, n - 1) 
File Main.py , line 14, in mult return m + mult(m, n - 1)
```

Comment: the code seems correct. could you please print the inputs, so we can see the exact ones that cause failures? this might be due to recursion depth limit (although that produces `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`).

Comment: Thank you for replying. Actually I am submitting this on online platform so I am also not aware of inputs.

Comment: You could try entering a large number for `n`, say something about 1000 (the default recursion limit) and see if you get the same error (the evaluation platform might hide parts of the error message, otherwise you could use that to print the inputs...)

Comment: Thank you Sir. I set recursion limit to `10000` and my code got accepted. So, it was recursion limit error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested your script for several inputs and found out that it does not work for higher numbers. For example, it is not working for m,n (3412 * 3412).
The reason for this is that the recursion depth in python which is 1000 by default is being crossed in your code.

To increase the recursion depth in python follow the steps:

1) import the sys module in your script and

2) At the beginning of your script 
Type this :

```
 sys.setrecursionlimit(1500)
```

This will increase the default limit(1000) to 1500.

Note: Though it works for your code up to some number, it is not a good solution. You need to improve your code.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Since your code works fine for other cases, I feel the error might be because of max recursion depth. You can do something like below, with out using recursion. Below code uses loops and addition, `for` and `sum`.

```
def mult(m, n):
    result = sum(m for _ in range(abs(n)))
    if n < 0:
        return -result
    else:
        return result


m = int(input())
n = int(input())
print(mult(m, n))
```

Output:

```
3
-12
-36
```

Answer (score 1):

Try one number greater than 1000 and check

python recursion limit is 1000 only you can change it by using 'sys' module

sys.setrecursionlimit(1500)

this might help.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for helping me out to find error. Actually it was recursion limit which was giving problem when I changed it to higher value as suggested by 'tobias_k' using

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(1000)
```

this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
def mul(m, n):
     return m if n == 1 else m + (m, n - 1)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It seems OPs issue was limit to recursion depth, if your solution reduces needed recursion depth please clarify that.

Comment: Besides the fact that this is a code-only answer, the code is also simply plain wrong. `mul(7,8)` gives `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'`.